# Automatically fill elementor form using request parameter

Tags: forms, elementor

On my site, I have a page with all the product options (not using woocomerce).
Under each product, there's a button that says 'request a quote'.
That button opens an elementor form.

I want one of the form's textboxes to be prefilled with the product title.

using [this](https://elementor.com/help/dynamic-request-parameter-pro/) information, I added the product title as a parameter to the page url when 'request a quote' was clicked.
For example, when clicking 'request a quote' for a product called 'my product', the url would look like this:https://my-site.com/products/?producttitle=my%20product

Then, I added a textbox in the form (see image) which uses a request parameter, type=get, parameter name = producttitle.
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lXEK.png)
I was expecting that the textbox would be filled with 'my product' since that is the 'producttitle'. Instead, nothing shows.

All help is appreciated!

update: something weird I'm noticing: When i refresh the page while the form is showing (with product 'my product' for example), and then click 'request a quote' on a different product (for example 'my second product), then the textbox gets prefilled with 'my product'.
So it seems like I'm doing something out of order.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

The url of the page only changed on button click, which is the same time that the form is triggered and the textbox prefilled.
That's why the textbox was not prefilling with parameters from the url - they didn't exist!

So it seems that the way I approached the issue of trying to prefill the textbox is not possible. In order to do that, I have to link each product to a separate page and have the 'request a quote' button on that page.
for example, the product 'my product' can have a button on it called 'view more' which when clicked takes the user to the url '/product/?producttitle=my-product'. On that page, there can be the 'request a quote' button which opens the form. Since the url of the page already has the parameter (producttitle) filled (my-product), it will prefill with the correct product.